# HTML Table with boxed entries

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table in the following format and I want to improve the design of the table. I would like to format the letters in the column 'Codes' in a kind of box shape, that is I want to draw a box around each letter (A B or C) and color the background of the box differently. How would you this ?

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Codes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>A B C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>B C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>A C</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: More importantly, what have you tried to do to solve this? - Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show examples of what you have tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CAN'T use JS, than only solution by using plain CSS is `tr td:last-child::first-letter {}` selector. It allows you to style first letter in last column of each row.

If you CAN use JS, you can use this JavaScript snippet

```
$("tr td:last-child").contents().each(function(){
if (this.nodeType == 3) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span class="letterbox">$&</span>"));
  } 
});
```

And this CSS

```
.letterbox { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; background-color: #ddd;}
```